# Deleting a file on server by DELETE form method

Tags: php, html

I am trying to delete a file on my server using **DELETE** method in my html form.

I have a file ,and url to that file is :

```
 http://example.com/file2.php
```

I am using the following code for deleting the file :

```
<form action="file2.php"method="DELETE">
<input type="submit"value="delete file">
</form>
```

When I press "delete file" button I get redirected to "file2.php" but it is not deleting the file.

Server is receving the request header in GET method :

```
GET /file2.php HTTP/1.1
```

instead of DELETE :

```
DELETE /file2.php HTTP/1.1
```

Does someone know why the delete method is not working? or how can I delete my file using DELETE method?

Comment: It's not a good method, not all browser support it. It's better to do it with php

Comment: Most browsers won't send the `delete` method. It get changed back to `get`. (I'm guessing: Because `delete` is old and didn't catch on so browsers stopped supporting it.)

Answer (score 4):

Most browser do not support `DELETE` as method parameter for `<form ...>`. Indeed it's not even part of the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#attr-fs-method):

> The *method* and *formmethod* content attributes are enumerated attributes with the following keywords and states:
>
> - The keyword *get*, mapping to the state **GET**, indicating the HTTP GET method.
> - The keyword *post*, mapping to the state **POST**, indicating the HTTP POST method.

And here is some kind of [explanation](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=10671):

> It seems that we currently do not understand how PUT and DELETE will be useful for HTML forms.
>
> For DELETE, it's indeed easy to create a useful request. However, server implementations usually respond with 200 and a minimal response body ("deleted") or 204 (no content). So it's not clear how this can be used in a web application.
>
> For PUT, it seems there's no real use case as long as the web page doesn't have full control over the payload, and also can set the content type.
>
> Please consider removing this feature until there's a clearer understanding about what it's good for.

Frameworks like [laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#form-method-spoofing) provide *method spoofing*:

```
<input type='_method' value='DELETE' />
```

This will override the *method* of the request and will - for example - call a destroy function:

```
Route::delete('/items/{id}', 'ItemController@destroy');
```

If you don't use a framework, you can try to mimic this behaviour:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'DELETE' || (isset($_REQUEST['_method'] && $_REQUEST['_method'] === 'delete') {
...
}
```

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking. Its part of HTTP specification, but was dropped from the HTML specification.

Answer (score 2):

Mozilla only [specifies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method) only `GET` and `POST`

I have 2 recommendations:

- Use a POST to send data to your PHP code and handle it from there
- Don't actually delete stuff that simple. Create some function that will just say it is deleted till after you are really sure it has to be gone